# 2 Poisson distributions questions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

An emission from a radioactive source is such that the number of emitted particles in a 10 seconds interval is well modeled by a random variable $X$, following Poisson's Law is such that $E(X^2)=6$. Calculate:

1. The probability of the emission of 2 particles in a 10 seconds period
2. The probability of the emission of at least 3 particles in a 10 seconds period

My doubt is the $E(X^2)=6$, I don't understand it, I already did the first one with a result of $4.46\%$.

I made like this:

$P(K)=\frac{e^{-\lambda}.\lambda^{k}}{K!}=$

$P(2)= \frac{e^{-6}.6^{2}}{2!}$

$\frac{0,002478.36}{2}=0.04464=4,46$

Am i missing something?

Comment: So you deleted your previous version of the post and reposted the same thing again?

Comment: Yes, because the last post was not well explained with an example of what i did to try to find a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is  that is that the mean and variance of a Poisson distribution are both equal to $\lambda$. In particular
$$
\lambda=\text{Var}(X)=EX^2-(EX)^2=6-\lambda^2\iff\lambda^2+\lambda-6=0 \quad (\lambda>0)
$$ 
Solve for $\lambda>0$ (hence you will reject one root) and note that in question 1 we seek
$$
P(X=2)=\frac{\lambda^2e^{-\lambda}}{2}
$$
while in question 2 we seek
$$
P(X\ge3)=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)-P(X=2)
$$